# Searching for a String and printing results using def__contains__()

Tags: python

I am trying to write a piece of code that can search for a string in graph and if it finds it, it will print a string indicating it was found. I think that the way I am searching for it using contains is correct, I am just having trouble understanding how I can print a string showing that information. Below is the section in question, specifically at def__contains__().

```
    def __contains__(self, item):
        if "EVGA" in self.graph: 
            print "Contains EVGA"
        else:
            print "Doesn't Contain EVGA"
```

Comment: This depends on what `self.graph` is. Also, you probably want to use `item`, not a hardcoded value of `"EVGA"`.

Answer (score 0):

I  hope I understand your question, but i am guessing you want to modify use `__contains__` to search for the string (graphics card name) and 
if found to print a statement that it contains that particular graphics card.
If so, you could modify the `__contains__` function in the `COMPUTER` class as like shown below:

```
def __contains__(self, item):
     if item in self.graph:
        print ("Contains {0}".format(item)) # this is optional
        return True 
     else:
        print ("Does not Contain {}".format(item)) # this is optional
        return False
```

when you run

```
print( "EVGA" in computer1)
print ("EVGA" in computer2)
print ("Gigabyte" in computer2)
```

you will get:

```
Contains EVGA
True
Does not Contain EVGA
False
Contains Gigabyte
True
```

**EDIT:** after comment mentioned by user2357112

Comment: Thank you this was the explanation I was hoping for.

Comment: `__contains__` is the method used to implement the `in` operator; you should never return a string from it. Doing so will break the use of the `in` operator.

Comment: @user2357112, thanks. I knew this will come up ;) I was just tying to give an explaination to the OP how one can print a statement. I understand what you are saying I will modify it according to your suggestion.